# Finding the number of options in multiple selects that have the same IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I do know that it is against best practice for multiple elements to have the same ID in a single page. However in this case I need for there to be two selects with the same id.

I have seen some success using this method:

```
$('#undo_redo_to option').length;
$('#undo_redo_to:eq(0) option').length;
*$('#undo_redo_to:eq(1) option').length;*
```

However, the code enclosed in *'s does not give me the proper length.

Please see the following pen, where I have created my selects and did my debugging.

[LINK TO CODE](http://codepen.io/CodeBroJohn/pen/aNymJK?editors=1011)

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's invalid HTML to have a repeated ID.

Comment: If you have the means, change your id to a class and target them that way.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the means. I was able to get my desired behavior using the method @Rick Hitchcock provided. I do appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've inherited the HTML and cannot change the ids to classes:

Note that `eq()` is a jQuery selector.  If you change it to `nth-child(2)`, you'll be using a CSS selector.  That gives you what you need:

```
$('#undo_redo_to:nth-child(2) option').length;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwERGW?editors=1011

Comment: Correct! Unfortunately, I am using a multiselect plugin http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/, so I have limited control over what I can call the ID/Class attributes.  
Thanks a ton sir, I just need those numbers so I can do further computing.
You have been a ton of help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that jQuery uses the native JS functions first, so when you do a `$('#this_id')` you are effectively calling `document.getElementById('this_id')`. it's not just against best practice, it actually won't work... you could loop through your selects and check the id:

```
$('select option').each(function(){
  if($(this).closest('select').attr('id')=='my_id'){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with native javascript, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id=undo_redo_to]")
```

You can do it with jquery like this:

```
$("[id=undo_redo_to]")
```

This is the property selector, as the `#`-type selector will stop searching when the first element having that `id` was found.

So you can do this using plain javascript or jquery, but don't do it, because `id` should be unique and if it is not unique, then the HTML is invalid and it is bad for SEO.